# How to return list of object using Ajax and Asp.net?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to return the list of object from server side code through ajax. It is returning successfully, But I cannot extract.

**Jquery Code**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            url: "MyWebService.asmx/Execute_SequenceNo",

            data: JSON.stringify({
                "journalEntry": $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtJournalEntry').val().trim()
            }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success = " + data.d.length + ', Data 0 =' + data.d[0] + ' ' + data.d[1])
            },
            error: function (result) {


            }
        })
```

The below code to get the records from my Sql Server

**WebService**

```
[WebMethod]
    public SequenceNumber[] Execute_SequenceNo(string journalEntry)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<SequenceNumber> details = new List<SequenceNumber>();
        try
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
                {


                    sequence.errorMsg = "Valid";
                    details.Add(sequence);
                }
            }
            return details.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            //return "NotValid error = " + ee.ToString();
            SequenceNumber sequence = new SequenceNumber();
            sequence.errorMsg = "NotValid";
            return details.ToArray();
        }


    }
```

> it return successfully, but my alert is like below

**Output**

```
Success = 2, Data 0 =[object Object] [object Object]
```

Comment: That alert looks reasonable to me.  What's the actual problem?  What are you expecting the alert to show and why?  Side note: Don't use `alert` for debugging, use `console.log`.  It's non-blocking, serializes complex types, maintains a running log, etc.

Comment: @David how to print the value of `sequence.journalEntry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to be working fine.  It just seems that you're expecting `alert()` to do something more than it does.  It doesn't serialize objects or display any given property that you might want from those objects.  Anything that's not a primitive value just gets displayed as:

```
[object Object]
```

The simplest approach for your debugging is to not use `alert()`.  Instead, use `console.log()`.  This has a few benefits:

- It's non-blocking, so the code can continue to execute with normal timing.  This reduces the possibility of timing bugs caused by code behaving very differently in debug vs. release scenarios.
- It serializes complex types, so you can fully examine your objects.
- It's not a dismissable dialog but instead an ongoing log.

Open your browser's debugging tools and take a look at the console.  Then in your code (in your `success` function where you currently use `alert()`) simply do something like:

```
console.log("Success = ", data);
```

Observe what's logged to the console.  For debugging this will give you an exact representation of what the complex object/array `data` is, what it's elements are, etc.  From there you can observe specifically how to access any given value within that object/array.

Comment: I tried with console. it prints `Success = [object Object]` the same

Comment: @Liamneesan: Can you update your code to show what you tried?

Comment: @Liamneesan: You're still using `alert()`.  Use `console.log()` instead.  (Refer to the answer above.)  Also, if your web service is returning XML, I would expect the client-side code to fail entirely as it's looking for JSON.  Put some debugging output in the `error` function as well, and observe any errors on the browser's development console.

Comment: Sorry, your code is working, Actually I tried like this `console.log("Success returns  = " + data + ', Data 0 =' + data.d[0].toString() + ' ' + data.d[1]);`, then it returns the same what I mentioned on my previous comment. But your code is working. `console.log("Success = ", data);`Thanks bro